# String encryption in C

Tags: c, encryption

There is given five letter encrypted word and he has to decrypt it. Each letter when shifted by a constant number d gives the decrypted letter. Write a C program.  Input:  In input, one five-letter word (small case letters) and a number d will be given. (0≤d≤10^3)
Output:  Print the decrypted five-letter word
Example:

```
Input: ajyqq 2 
Output: class
```

Comment: What you're looking for is a version of the caeser cipher, this cipher rotates characters by 3 places. Another algorithm is the ROT(n) algorithm popularly implemented as ROT(13). But before we help, Can you show us what you have done already?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to input the string and number with something like `scanf`.

You need to process each character of the string (which are actually integral types) with a `for` loop (controlled by `strlen` on the string), adding the number to each and possibly detecting if it's greater than `z` and wrapping it (by subtracting 26).

Then you need to output the new string with something like `printf`.

Those are the keywords you should look into for your education. The *pseudo-code* for such a beast would be:

```
scanf (string, integer) -> str, val
for i = 0 to strlen(str) - 1 inclusive:
    str[i] = str[i] + val
    if str[i] > 'z':
        str[i] = str[i] - 26
    if str[i] < 'a':
        str[i] = str[i] + 26
printf (str)
```